# Issues Install Django in my Current python -V Python 3.9.6

Tags: python, django, pip

I have an issue while installing `Django`.
`ERROR: No matching distribution found for django`

```
C:\Users\rajesh-kumar>python -V
Python 3.9.6

C:\Users\rajesh-kumar>pip -V
pip 21.1.3 from c:\users\rajesh-kumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

C:\Users\rajesh-kumar>pip install django
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_DECODE_ERROR] tlsv1 alert decode error (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_DECODE_ERROR] tlsv1 alert decode error (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_DECODE_ERROR] tlsv1 alert decode error (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_DECODE_ERROR] tlsv1 alert decode error (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_DECODE_ERROR] tlsv1 alert decode error (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/django/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/django/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_DECODE_ERROR] tlsv1 alert decode error (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_DECODE_ERROR] tlsv1 alert decode error (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping
```

Comment: [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751768/10217732)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

After that

```
virtualenv venv
```

Then activate your environment

```
source  venv/bin/activate
```

And now you can install Django, I think this is better way and safe, rather than install django in a global system.

```
pip install django
```